# POST to ASP.NET Web API from Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API. I am trying to POST a string to an endpoint. My ASP.NET Web API endpoint looks like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test(string name)
{
  int i = 0;
  i = i + 1;
  return Ok();
}
```

In Fiddler, I execute the following request from the composer:

```
POST http://localhost:8089/api/MyApiController/test
```

If I remove "string name" as the parameter, I can successfully execute my API endpoint. When string name is there, I get a 405 error. So, I added the following in the "Request Body" section in Fiddler:

```
John
```

Unfortunately, that still causes a 405 to be thrown. I can't tell if I'm setting up my Web API endpoint wrong if I'm setting up my request in fiddler incorrectly. My full request looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8089/api/MyApiController/test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:8089
Content-Length: 26
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8        

{ "name" : "John"}
```

The response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRWNvZmljXFNvbGlkUVxKTExcamxsLW1hcmtldHNwaGVyZVxXZWJzaXRlXGFwaVxTZWFyY2hBcGlcaW5kZXg=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 15:51:50 GMT
Content-Length: 73

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
```

I don't understand why POST is allowed when I do not have a parameter. Yet, when I add a parameter, POST does not work.

[Update]
I added the following in my C# code:

```
var content = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I figured the JSON would be in the `content`. However, `content` is just an empty string.

Comment: Dont forgot the `Content-Type: application/json` header in the request.

Comment: Looks like you need a `[FromBody]` attribute on `string name` as you aren't including it in the URI.

Comment: @peco - I added Content-Type. Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem.

Comment: @NWard - I added [FromBody]. Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the "Composer" tab:

[image]I suggest you should try with following url

```
http://localhost:8089/api/MyApi/test
```

I think that problem is with route.

You should have some route like following  as default route just have controller/id. This route comes before default route.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi1",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { action="test" }
            );
```

Also you action should look like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test([Frombody]string name)
{
  int i = 0;
  i = i + 1;
  return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I am still receiving a 405 when I POST to the action as long as it has a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

in the body part of the composer try

```
{ "name" : "somtext"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get a 405.

Answer (score 1):

Below, I modified the datatype of the parameter from string to object, and had success.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post( [ FromBody ] **object** items )
{
    Console.WriteLine( items );
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the body you need to add Json or XML syntax, not just then name for The Asp.Net Deserialiser to do its thing. Json would be:

```
{ "name" : "John" }
```

EDIT: Your url route also seems incorrect, if you are using the default routes. By default it will be picked up as: `POST http://localhost:8089/api/MyApiController/` the "test" part is omitted as it recognises this as a POST method. Your action should also specify that the parameter you take in ("name") is expected from the body `public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test([FromBody]string name)`. Now your url will match if you do something like:

```
`POST http://localhost:8089/api/MyApiController/`
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:8089
Content-Length: 26

{ "name" : "John" }
```

Comment: Okay, a little more detail may be needed. Can you add the full request from fiddler to your post? Might also be useful to show how/where your routes are defined too (i.e. default routing or attribute routes?).

Comment: I added the full text of both the request and the response to the question above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user687554 updated my answer. I tested this and seems to work. Also tested how you described originally and also got a 405, as described in the edit.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think its much closer. When I post from Fiddler, my breakpoint is getting hit. However, the parameter value is always `null`. Why would that be?

Comment: May also need to add a header specifying you're using json. Content-Type:application/json

Comment: I did that. Still getting null.

Comment: Would expect this to work. The json is being placed in the right section of fiddler? Maybe screenshot it. And the parameter of the action matches the json property name?